# CSS - how to specify unit of a calc()?

Tags: css

Assume I want the following styling:

```
font-size: 3rem;
```

However, I do not want to hardcode the 3. Rather, I want it to be a result of a `calc()` operation (e.g. `calc(2 + 1)`). How do I specify the unit `rem` to follow the results of the `calc()` operation? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
font-size: calc(2 + 1)rem;
```

I guess I'm looking for a concatenation feature? CSS solution only, please.

Comment: Why are your values in calc unitless?

Comment: Assume they are variables that cannot have units.

Comment: @StackOverflowNewbie CSS custom-properties can have units though...

Comment: Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019567/13304024

Comment: @IvanBeliakov - I think your link should work for me. Do you want to put that down as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mentioned variables. So the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50019567/13304024) may be useful.

Use variable in `calc` and multiply it by 1 with the needed unit:

```
font-size: calc(var(--size) * 1rem);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd *want* to do this, but you *could*:

```css
font-size: calc((2 + 1) * 1rem);
```